Rapid API doesn't parse/converts array correctly into pyhton code
I am trying to create a Get Request method where "keywords" is the key and array object is a value.

As seen from the picture, Rapid API converts this into following code:
import requests

url = "https://example.rapidapi.com"

querystring = {"keywords":"[\"value1\",\"value2\"]"}


response = requests.get(url, params=querystring)

print(response.json())

Pay attention to "keywords" value. It's completely false formatting and syntax. Has anyone else had a similar issue with Rapid API. Is there any solution to this just a bug, or something else?
